# Appflow Update_flow error : Destination object for the destination connector can not be updated

Tags: json, aws-lambda, runtime-error, amazon-appflow

Anyone faced this error while calling update_flow for appflow?

```
errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateFlow operation: Update Flow request failed due to:[Destination object for the destination connector can not be updated]",
  "errorType": "ValidationException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.update_flow (\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 357, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 676, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
```

What could be the cause.

Comment: This is resolved. Appflow doesnt allow to change the destination folders using update_flow. you have to set it exact same as existing flow

Comment: Hi @User2019, are you deploying AppFlow with CloudFormation? What does your template look like?

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved. Appflow doesnt allow to change the destination folders using update_flow. you have to set it exact same as existing flow.